# Site Hangs on Test Server after Framework and SQL updates

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

This is an odd issue that we just can’t quite figure out. On our test server we had an instance of SQL Express as well as SQL Server 2008 R2 running our test database. We added a “playground” database so we could start messing around with a rewrite. We agreed to go ahead and start working with SQL Server 2012 for the new app that will be a MVC4 with a mixture of EF5 and SPROCS (and FileTables).

We first pushed the MVC4 app (that is only UI at this point with a little EF in it for an Error Handler I wrote) on to the test sever and we had to upgrade the framework on the server to 4.5 to see it. Everything seemed to work. So then I installed a new instance of SQL Server 2012, and also installed the service pack.

For the odd part…we hooked up our old app (web forms) to the 2008R2 instance, and it just hanged at login, but then it would occasionally go through. We tied the old app back to the SQL Server Express version, and still the same hang up. Ok, so there is a hang up somewhere, maybe on SQL, right? The gotcha is it ONLY hangs up in IE and Chrome on a Windows system. It works fine in firefox on windows. And it works fine in Chrome/Safari/Firefox on a mac. From time to time, I CAN log in on Chrome via windows, but a few minutes later if I try again, back to hanging.

Things we’ve tried since: Restarting the server, uninstalling 4.5 framework, checking logs (I don’t see anything of concern), reinstalled 4.5, used Fiddler and then used chrome on a windows machine (and it flew straight through), made sure that our old app was still targeted for the 4.0 framework in IIS, and banged our heads on the keyboard.

If anyone can shed some light on this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error of tracing back what could be the problem, we uninstalled the 4.5 .Net Framework update and re-installed 4.0 and it all went back to normal.  Although we can't test out our 4.5 app, we were under the impression 4.5 was more of a side by side thing with 4.0.  We even made sure that our old app was targeting 4.0, but it made no difference.

If anyone has insight on how to make 4.5 and 4.0 work nicely together on the same server, please let me know!